# How can I set error info for my home page

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
if($evaluation_sheet_t3 == 0) {
      $error_eval = $error_eval.'Term 3,';
      $error_eval = substr($error_eval,0,strlen($error_eval)-1);
      $error_info = "The ".$error_eval." evaluations are not completed.";  
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error_info',$error_info);  
      redirect(base_url().'teacher_manager/term_wise_sheet_data/'.$term_value.'/'.$class_name1.'/'.$subject_id,'refresh');
}
```

Above is my controller.

Answer (score 2):

In php you can turn 'on' errors/notices/warning, etc. with this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Hope it will help you.

[EDIT]
In addition, you can send one var through redirection with method '->with('varName', $var)

Something like this:

You can add one var with method '->with()', something like this:

```
    redirect(base_url().'teacher_manager/term_wise_sheet_data/'.$term_value.'/'.$class_name1.'/'.$subject_id,'refresh')
            ->with('errors', $error_info);
```